# str.ljust() not producing changes to pandas column(series) (using to sort values)

Tags: string, sorting, pandas

Cabin_Fare.Cabin.head(20) (produces these results)

```
583    A10
208    A11
475    A14
556    A16
331    A18
284    A19
599    A20
28     A21
630    A23
867    A24
647    A26
112    A29
209    A31
185    A32
445    A34
293    A34
374    A34
806    A36
96      A5
23      A6
```

I assign it to x and convert the object types to string type.

```
x = Cabin_Fare.Cabin.astype('string')
```

I'm trying to push values like A5/A6 (The last two values) one space to the left, because when the column is being sorted, any values with only a len of 2 aren't being sorted properly. I'm assuming because they aren't aligned equally with those values having a len of 3.

So I tried to run this code but I'm not seeing any changes made (the A5/A6 aren't being pushed one space to the left)

```
for i in x[x.notnull()]:
    if len(i) == 2:
        i= i.ljust(3,)
```

Edit: I'm trying to utilize Boud's solution and I'm running into a problem because there are values/instances where only the letter (no numbers)is present. 
The error shows up as:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''
```

To circumvent this, I'm trying to add a '0' to the values where only the letter is present.

```
for i in x:
    if len(i)==1:
        i = i+'0'
```

However, the changes are not sticking outside of the loop, just within.

Comment: `df.Cabin.str.ljust(3)` does everything you want.  If you are having a sorting problem, then ask that question.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I don't understand why my loop didn't work though. When I ran my loop,despite no errors, A5 and A6 didn't get pushed to the left as it did when I ran your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your values don't have a leading space, actually. Sorting against strings will apply the alphabetical order, which is character by character. All strings start with an `A`, then the second character is a digit, and 5 and 6 are digits that are greater than 0, 1, 2, and 3 in your example. So the numbers are considered are numbers, but as a sequence of single digit.

If you want a sort by the numbers following `A`, extract the number by removing the first character, convert into `int`, sort that series of int, and then reindex `x` based on the resulting index of that proper sort:

```
x.reindex(x.str[1:].astype(int).sort_values().index)
Out[57]: 
18     A5
19     A6
0     A10
1     A11
2     A14
3     A16
4     A18
5     A19
6     A20
7     A21
8     A23
9     A24
10    A26
11    A29
12    A31
13    A32
14    A34
15    A34
16    A34
17    A36
Name: Cabin, dtype: object
```

Comment: For some reason, when I run the above code on the entire series(not just the sample), I get this error:
`ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''`
Do you have any idea what the problem could be? I did do some data cleaning, where I dropped some values if there were multiple values in a slot.

Comment: It means you have entries say with one character only, so the first and sole character is removed , and astype cannot convert it

Comment: Ah! Thanks.To resolve this problem,  I'm trying to add '0' to the entries where there is only one character  via iteration:
`for i in x:
 if len(i)==1:
  i = i+'0'`

But the changes only occur within the for loop; once outside the loop the changes are non-existent. 

I wrote the code in here, but if it's illegible, I will update the OP.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Add replace('', 0) before the astype call

Comment: So the next error, I"m getting is:
`cannot convert float NaN to integer`
which I'm trying to reconcile through this code:
`x[x.notnull()].reindex( x[x.notnull()].str[1:].replace('', 0).astype(int).sort_values().index)`
But now I'm getting this error: 
`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this error.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's best I create a new thread as I'm still waiting for PirSquared's answer which is a different problem.